# Why is this line " Worshipping thy lotus feet " present in all puranas?

Tags: puranas, shiva-purana, devi-bhagavata-purana

Be it shiva purana or Bhagavadam , the praises for most of the gods begin with similar kind of line like

> O Brahmins! I bow down to the gentle lotus feet, known in the three
>   Lokas, of the Devî Bhagavatî, praised by Brahmâ and the other devas
>   Visnu, Mahes’a and others

Why does feet of gods/goddess gets special attention for their worship in puranas ? what is the story or significance behind it, does it mean we have to worship them by remembering their feet ? instead of their face.

Comment: Feet of Sri Vishnu are like padma(lotus), he is also called pundarikaksha (lotus-eyed). When you want to ask for forgiveness from someone, or show them ultimate form of respect, what do you do.. fall at their feet, right ? same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must have to do with the generation of devotion, surrender etc.

According to the following nirukti of Purana (why it is so called), as given by Lord Shiva in the Kularnava Tantram (which is a Shakta Agama text), one of the major features of Puranas is their devotion or bhakti aspect. They serve to build devotion in the readers or hearers' minds.

> **Pu**nya PApAdi KathanaAd **RA**kshashA DinibAranAt| **Na**vabhaktyAdi JananAt PurAn Iti Kathyate ||
>
> ..........
>
> Because it tells of merit and demerit (Punyapapa), because it dispels
>   evil beings like Raksasas, and **because it generates nine-fold
>   devotion, (Navabhakti) and the like, it is called Purana.**
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 17.39.**

Now, the feet is surely the place for surrender which in turn is related to devotion.

So, this is why i think the concept of surrendering to/worshiping the lotus feet of God is extensively found in all the Puranas as the very nature of those texts is certainly bhakti pradhana and one of their purposes too is to generate bhakti.

Answer (score 2):

This is very interesting and good question.

We often see the term “Lotus feet” in all our Puranas, Bhakti literature and in various other spiritual books. The term lotus feet represents the Divine feet of Gods, Saints,  Gurus, Acharyas  and other Spiritual beings.

The feet of the Gods , Saints, Gurus, Acharya etc. are compared to the lotus .The concept is  the  softness  , divinity of the feet can be only compared with the delicate lotus petals.The lotus is soft , sublime and also sacred so are the lotus feet of these.

Now in Hinduism lotus is a spiritual symbol , the actual meaning of which is Spiritual progress, pureness, knowledge etc. The another meaning of the lotus Feet is also transcendental , or very deep , and beyond our understanding.

A student , devotee or a disciple expresses his devotion , surrender dedication and love  , humility etc towards his chosen God , Guru , spiritual master etc. By touching , meditating at their  Its Lotus feet. In this way a relation with all these also gets established.

There is another concept which is called “Sharanagati” means falling upon the lotus feet of the God , Guru , OR Spiritual masters ,to illuminate our soul and to attain the state of Moksha. This also signifies giving away all our ego and completely taking shelter at feet of these.

We here can see the softness of the feet of Shree Rama is compared with that of lotus.

> गुर्वर्थे त्यक्तराज्यो व्यचरदनुवनं  पद्मपद्मपद्भ्यां प्रियाया:।
>   पाणिस्पर्शाक्षमाभ्यां मृजितपथरुजो यो हरीन्द्रानुजाभ्याम ।।
>
> gurv-arthe tyakta-rājyo vyacarad  anuvanaṁ padma-padbhyāṁ priyāyāḥ
>   pāṇi-sparśākṣamābhyāṁ mṛjita-patha rujo yo harīndrānujābhyām
>
> To keep the promise of His father intact, Lord Rāmacandra immediately
>   gave up the position of king and, accompanied by His wife, mother
>   Sītā, wandered from one forest to another on His lotus feet, which
>   were so delicate that they were unable to bear even the touch of
>   Sītā’s palms.[SB 9.10.4](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/10/4)
>
> ---
>
> त्सर्वश्रुतिशिरोरत्नविराजित पदाम्बुजः ।
>    वेदान्ताम्बुजसूर्योयः तस्मै श्रीगुरवे नमः ॥
>
> tsarvashrutishiroratnaviraajita padaambujaH
>  vedaantaambujasuuryoyaH
>   tasmai shriigurave namaH
>
> Salutation to the noble Guru, whose lotus feet are radiant with (the
>   luster of) the crest jewel of all Srutis and who is the sun that
>   causes the Vedanta Lotus (knowledge) to blossom.  [**here**](http://sanskrit.samskrutam.com/en.literature-shloka-guru-vandanaa.ashx)

These are some quick  examples of lotus feet concept you want to know.
There are  literally thousands of such  example scattered in our vast literature. Some of which I will add later on in my answer.

Comment: OP is not asking why feet are compared to lotus... But he is asking **why its the feet and not say the face etc**.. Also its not only the feet that are compared to lotus in Hindu scriptures, we have Padmalochana (lotus eyed) , Padmavadana (lotus faced).. Also u need to explain why Puranas are emphasizing on the feet? that is also part of OP's question.. So if feet is related to Bhakti or surrender..then u need to prove that Puranas are Bhakti Pradhana literature..but did u prove that?